# Scanner defect on integrated Zxing library (android 2.2)

Tags: android, zxing

I've successfully integrating Zxing 2.1 sources into my android project.

After calling this onButtonScan():

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

---

Result shown on android 2.2(HTC sense):

1. Scanning area seems small and not placed at the middle.
2. What scanning shows is totally up-side-down.

Result shown on android 4.1(S4):

1. Works fine.

Could anyone figured what is wrong?Is it the minimum android version got to be > 2.2?

Comment: Have you asked in the zxing group? https://code.google.com/p/zxing/issues/list

Comment: Have you tried through programmatically ?

Comment: @kirtiavaiya Programmatically? which means?

Comment: @323go I have been adding their source into my project, I don't think they will like what I've asked.

Comment: @Roylee Means to change your scanning area and make it in to center programmatically

Comment: @kirtiavaiya I've not down to that part yet, which part I should configure? But it works nice in android 4?

Comment: @Roylee i tried in earlier version but not in android4,so you can explore it,if it works,then its better

Comment: @kirtiavaiya So you experienced the same thing as I did now? I mean on previous zxing version.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26686/discussion-between-roylee-and-kirti-avaiya)